# Jackson ObjectMapper deserialize Map with Json string key

Tags: java, json, jackson

The task is create correct Json string representation. There are Map that may contains value that Json string. During write this map to string mapper escape new line and quote Json.

```
private String getJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "val1");
    map.put("key2", "val2");
    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);
}
```

return:

```
{
  "key1" : "val1",
  "key2" : "val2"
}
```

Code

```
public String test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("information", getJson());
    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result; 
}
```

return

```
{"information":"{\r\n  \"key1\" : \"val1\",\r\n  \"key2\" : \"val2\"\r\n}"}
```

But is it possible for  test() method return String like:

```
{
  "information": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can **Map<String,String>** in the test method be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in console output. Map has value as string. If you want formmating output you can put map with "key1", "key2" in your map with key "information" and call `mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map)`

Comment: Task is get nested json structure (tree) not plain like you suggest

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert JSON back to map before putting it to "information" map. In your code it is treated just as a string not a map.
So you have to update your `test()` method to something like this:

```
public static String test() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {};
    Map<String, String> oldMap = mapper.readValue(getJson(), typeRef);

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("information", oldMap);

    String result = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result; 
}
```

And the outptut is

```
{
  "information" : {
    "key1" : "val1",
    "key2" : "val2"
  }
}
```